# FileUploder get file full path using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I use below code for getting full file path

My problem is using file.value in firefox only get my file name but in ie it get file full path

```
 function setImage(file) {        
        document.getElementById('prevImage').src = file.value;        
}
  <asp:FileUpload ID="fup" runat="server" onchange="setImage(this);" />
  <img id="prevImage" height="200" width="200"></img>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<inpu type="file" />` is a one of those elements which most browser even wont enable to change the style because of the security implications. Each browser has it's own level of security implementation.

I don't know why IE is providing you the full path, when the website to which it is uploading does not need that information

I don't see a reason why you may want the users file location(full path) on the server side, and it is a good thing that firefox is not providing the full path.

Comment: I want to preview the image when fileuploder upload file so how can i do that??

Comment: It is not possible to access the users file system from your browser(without using some Activex or 3rd party components) that run on the client machine, you can only view the image once it is uploaded to the server, before saving you can show the image and ask the user to confirm it using [HttpHandlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx)

Comment: You may also like to see upload controls like [Ajax Uploader](http://ajaxuploader.com/Demo/)